# Add ImageView to FingerPaint View

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I've created fingerpaint app. from finger paint android example API.
(SAMPLE: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java)

Now i've created an function to create a bitmap from paint (and move). This is my code:

```
public void addProgrammatlyImage(int pos[], String filePath){
    // Let's create the missing ImageView
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

    // Now the layout parameters, these are a little tricky at first
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

    Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("TOUCH!!");
            switch(event.getActionMasked())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                offset_x = (int)event.getX();
                offset_y = (int)event.getY();
                selected_item = v;

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    // Let's get the root layout and add our ImageView
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.vg1);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.xxx));
    layout.bringToFront();
    ((FrameLayout) layout).addView(image, 0, params);
}
```

My problem is:

- if inflate the new image on the same level of fingerpaint view (MyView class in the sample), disappear on the background (fingerpaint is in front of the image).
- i'm unable to insert image as child of MyView. In this case there is a problem when inflate the image: `classcast exception`, can't cast view (MyViewClass) to `ViewGroup`.

Can you help me please??